# Bipartite graph. average degree. Euler circuit.

Tags: bipartite-graphs, eulerian-path

This is such a hard question to get my head around. Can anyone help solve this?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? I've solved it. Waiting for your workings.

Comment: How many edges does $K_{1,1}$ have? How about $K_{1,2}?\ K_{2,2}?\ K_{2,3}?$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following: If you have $m+n$ vertices and the bipartite graph is complete, then you can send an edge from each of the $m$ vertices on one side to each of the $n$ vertices on the other side. Since for each $m$ you have $n$ possibilities, then $e(K_{m,n})=mn$.

 
Now the degree of each vertex on the $V_0$ side is $n$ since the graph is complete bipartite. Then a vertex on $V_0$ is connected to each of the $m$ on $V_1$. The same reasoning applies to the vertices on $V_1$, the degree for each vertex on $V_1$ is $m$. It follows that the average degree is $\dfrac{m+n}{2}$.

**EDIT:** I got the numbers messed around. Thanks @bof for the comment.

The average degree is **NOT** $\dfrac{m+n}{2}$. The average degree is $\dfrac{2mn}{m+n}$. This is because the sum of the degrees of $V_0$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^mn=mn$ and the sum of the degrees on $V_1$ is $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nm=nm$. Then, we add these quantities and divide by the total number of vertices to obtain $\dfrac{mn+nm}{m+n}=\dfrac{2mn}{m+n}$.

Now, a graph has an Eulerian circuit if each vertex has even degree. Then for even values of $m$ and $n$, $K_{m,n}$ will have an Eulerian circuit.

**EDIT:** Thanks again for the correction @bof. Indeed, we requiere the graph to be connected for the condition to hold.

I think that this other links can help you as well:

[Hamilton,Euler circuit,path](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221512/hamilton-euler-circuit-path)

[eulerian bipartite complete graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292092/eulerian-bipartite-complete-graph)

http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/jozef/MA210/07sol.pdf

Comment: Good. By the way, you could get the numerator $2mn$ in one step: the sum of the degrees is equal to twice the number of edges.